# How do I create a Drag Strip Material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, roughness

So I´ve been trying for multiple hours now to create a drag strip material. But because im relatively unexperienced when it comes to complicated materials I was hoping maybe that someone here could help me out. In the picture you can see the node setup that i got (Noise textures stretched going into a Brightness/Contrast node to a color ramp into the roughness of a .6 metallic black principled node with 0 specular and no clearcoat) after some tries but it´s still far off from looking realistic. The Main problem is this kind of glossy overlay on the track that looks like a rough, sticky white. I tried plugg[image]ing my node setup in the roughness and the (turned on) [image]clearcoat but I´m really getting nowhere. Any help would be much appreciated :)